# Video streaming from URL - webserver using video intent is not working

Tags: android, video-streaming

I am trying to play a video from a webserver using Intents.

I've been testing on two devices:

1. Google Pixel (API 29)
2. Samsung  Galaxy S6 (API 24)

On the first one the video plays on the build-in Media player without an issue.
On the second device the video fails to play with an error:

```
Couldn't open [VIDEO URL]: : java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: [ VIDEO URL]

0-10-25 18:33:24.783 19961-19961/? D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException | SecurityException happend : java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: [VIDEO URL]
```

and a bit later in the logcat:

```
2020-10-25 18:33:29.603 19961-19961/? E/VideoDB: setResumePosition - Exception occured:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI
```

The code I am using is:

```
    val videoUri = Uri.parse(getVideoUrl(videoId))
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, videoUri)
    intent.setDataAndType(videoUri, "video/mp4")
    startActivity(intent)
```

Why is the video not playing on the device with API 24? Are there any additional configurations that I have to do?

Do I have to download the video on the device and then play it? If yes some references/guidelines on that will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is the value returned by `getVideoUrl(videoId)` that is not working?

Comment: @CommonsWare It is a valid URL, `http://[server url].[file name].mp4`. If i open it with the browser, the video is playing.

Comment: Try to use `https` URLs, as cleartext communications (`http`) is banned by default on newer versions of Android. You can set up your [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) to allow cleartext traffic, but this is not great from a security standpoint.

Comment: It's `https`, excuse me

Comment: First, my apologies -- the network security configuration affects your app, and I forget that you were launching another app, and the problem was there. Note that there is no single "build-in Media player" in Android. The app that responds to `ACTION_VIEW` for your URL will vary by device. In this case, whatever is being launched on your Samsung does not like your URL for some reason, and it is not obvious from that Logcat message why it would be unhappy.

Comment: I attached a screenshot with the error I'm getting. Do you thing it's related with the device and not with the Android version?

Comment: Off the cuff, this appears to be a bug in that Samsung video player. Based on that stack trace, it seems like it is not handling `https` URLs correctly, feeding it to a `MediaPlayer` API that only works with `content` `Uri` values. This does not seem like an Android issue. But, you might consider installing a third-party player and see if it supports `ACTION_VIEW` for your URL (i.e., you get a chooser) and see if it can play the video back correctly.

Comment: I just tried it to open it with `Google Photos` and `VLC`. The first one works fine. The latest opens the app, loads for a while and then it close (looks like a crash?) and goes back to my app